# Shape of locus of point R

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> AO and BO are two fixed straight rods. PQ is a straight rod such that P and Q slide respectively on AO and BO. At each position of P and Q lines PR and QR are drawn perpendicular to AO and BO respectively. Show that the locus of R is the arc of a circle.

My approach was to try and show that angles subtended at R were equal, but could not proceed very far. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$OR$ is always the diameter of circumcircle of $\triangle POQ$. Since $OR$ subtends right angles at $P$ and $Q$.

From sine rule, $$OR = \frac{PQ}{\sin \angle AOB} = k \,\text{(constant)}$$

Thus $R$ moves on the circle with center $O$ and radius $k$.

Comment: PRQ is the supplement of AOB, and hence is fixed,so how do we use this fact?

Comment: @D.Spencer I improved my answer. Please see.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer,it was very helpful.